# Why some of the variables are not working affecting the drawn circle in runtime and in editor mode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is drawing a circle around the object it's attached.

The problem is that the two variables' segments and height have no effect on the circle either in editor mode or in runtime.  other variables do affect.

How can I use these two variables to affect the drawn circle?

another feature I would like to add is to add a bool flag variable and if it's true to make the drawn circle to be filled.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnityEngine.LineRenderer))]
public class DrawTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1, 50)] public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float xRadius = 5;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float yRadius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5)] public float width = 0.1f;
    [Range(0, 100)] public float height = 0;
    public bool controlBothXradiusYradius = false;
    public bool draw = true;

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask targetLayers;
    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if (draw)
            CreatePoints();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, xRadius, targetLayers))
        {
            Debug.Log("player detected");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("player NOT detected");
        }
    }

    public void CreatePoints()
    {
        var segments = 360;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.startWidth = width;
        line.endWidth = width;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;

        var pointCount = segments + 1; // add extra point to make startpoint and endpoint the same to close the circle
        var points = new Vector3[pointCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
        {
            var rad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * (i * 360f / segments);
            points[i] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(rad) * xRadius, 0, Mathf.Cos(rad) * yRadius);
        }

        line.SetPositions(points);
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private float prevXRadius, prevYRadius;
    private int prevSegments;
    private float prevWidth;
    private float prevHeight;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // Can't set up our line if the user hasn't connected it yet.
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (!line) return;

        if (!draw)
        {
            // instead simply disable the component
            line.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise re-enable the component
            // This will simply re-use the previously created points
            line.enabled = true;

            if (xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments || width != prevWidth || height != prevHeight)
            {
                CreatePoints();

                // Cache our most recently used values.
                prevXRadius = xRadius;
                prevYRadius = yRadius;
                prevSegments = segments;
                prevWidth = width;
                prevHeight = height;
            }

            if (controlBothXradiusYradius)
            {
                yRadius = xRadius;

                CreatePoints();
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: `var segments = 360;` creates a new variable that hides the member variable.

Comment: @RetiredNinja right , so i removed the var and left it as segments = 360; but now in the editor mode i can't change the segments value it's moving it back all the time to the 360 value.  not like the other variables that i can change the values.

Comment: Well, you can have it one way or the other. If you want the inspector to set the value then you shouldn't set it in the code. If you want the code to set the value then you shouldn't expect to be able to change it in the inspector.

Comment: @RetiredNinja why when I set the segments even to 360 if i zoom in close to the circle, I still see some segments missing?  very few but still some missing.  do i need to use shader or texture with the linerenderer to create smooth complete circle?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question it is already being answered in the comments. Also, while performing circular rendering, insufficient precision in angle approximation may lead to a discontinuous appearance in the graphics. Consider increasing the number of interpolation points to enhance precision, e.g. 360 -> 1000 or higher.